# How do i create my own convolution code on Matlab without using the built-in function

Tags: matlab, convolution

I am trying to create a program on Matlab to show the convolution of 2 signals but without using the 'conv' function.

The input is  ()=xp(-4t+4)*(−1)+0.5(−5)+2(−10)

I have worked out that h(t) = 4*exp(-4t)*u(t). I am trying to make a program on MATLAB to compute and display the convolution of two arrays representing two signals but without using the built-in 'conv' function.
I have a working code but it includes 'conv' and so I am trying to do it without using this.

```
t=linspace(0,11,1101);  

%create more than 500 time-series values

vs=exp(-4*(t-1)).*heaviside(t-1)+0.5*heaviside(t-5)+2*dirac(t-10);

%Input signal array

h=4*exp(-4*t).*heaviside(t);

%Input signal array

vc=conv(vs,h);

t1=linspace(0,22,2201);

%Convolution of two arrays

subplot(3,1,1)

plot(t,vs)

xlabel('t')

ylabel('v_s(t)')

title('Input signal')

subplot(3,1,2)

plot(t,h)

xlabel('t')

ylabel('h(t)')

title('System impulse response')

subplot(3,1,3)

plot(t1,vc)

xlabel('t')


ylabel('v_c(t)')

title('Output signal')
```

Comment: Please search for your question before posting here. There are literally hundreds of questions on here from people posting their convolution code and asking what is wrong with it. You can take any of those, fix them according to posted answers, and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the conv line with this:

```
N = length(vs);
M = length(h);   
lout=N+M-1;
vc=zeros(1,lout); 
for i = 1:N
    for k = 1:M
      vc(i+k-1) = vc(i+k-1) + h(k)*vs(i);
    end
end
```

It is a basic matlab implementation of the convolution formula